# Finishing rooms in blender or unreal engine?

Tags: modeling, unreal-engine

I realize this might be a dumb question, but here goes.

So I'm creating a game in unreal engine. My game will have multiple rooms. So I'm wondering if it would be better to create and put together all the rooms in blender, then exporting them to unreal? Or if I should create all the models in blender, then exporting the models to unreal and putting the room together in unreal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its better to export everything you modeled first, then position the objects in unreal

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on reusing assets, I would highly recommend exporting each 'thing' separately.  Then you can assemble, duplicate, and reuse them to your hearts content in Unreal.
If you are absolutely sure that every single thing will not be reused, then it would be faster to export it all at once, but you would lose future adaptability without having to re-model it in Blender.

I would go with the first option, which will almost certainly save you time in the long run.

Good luck, and have fun!